# Replace a specific element in a Groovy list

Tags: string, list, groovy, replace

I have a requirement to modify certain elements inside a Groovy list based on a condition. For e.g.

```
def rowmbrs = [DW, PL01, ENT, ACCT]
```

I need to run a condition like - if one of the elements in the above list is PL01 then replace it with GL01. If you can give me a hint or some examples to achieve this requirement, that will be great. Thanks in advance.

Expected Result after running the logic

```
[DW, GL01, ENT, ACCT]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
Collections.replaceAll(rowmbrs, "PL01", "TEST")
```

Comment: I tried other suggestions as well but this worked for me better. Thanks Prateek.

Answer (score 6):

You can use groovy style mapping function:

```
​def rowmbrs = ['DW', 'PL01', 'ENT', 'ACCT']
rowmbrs.collect {
    it == 'PL01' ? 'GL01' : it
}​
```

or if you need to change only one element you can use the index of it's element:

```
rowmbrs[rowmbrs.indexOf('PL01')] = 'GL01'​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Answer (score 1):

if the order is not important:

```
def rowmbrs = ['DW', 'PL01', 'ENT', 'ACCT']
rowmbrs = rowmbrs - 'PL01' + 'GL01'
assert '[DW, ENT, ACCT, GL01]' == rowmbrs.toString()
```